# When is a $k$-distance-transitive graph already distance-transitive?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory, symmetry

Call a (finite and connected) graph *$k$-distance-transitive* if its symmetry group acts transitively on the pairs in each one of the sets

$$D_\delta:=\{(i,j)\in V\times V\mid \mathrm d(i,j)=\delta\},\qquad\text{for all $\delta\in\{0,...,k\}$}.$$

For $k=\mathrm{diam}(G)$ (the diameter of $G$), these are the [*distance-transitive graphs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-transitive_graph).

> **Question:** Is it known that if $k$ is just large enough (e.g. relative to $\mathrm{diam}(G)$, or in an absolute sense), that every $k$-distance-transitive graph is already distance-transitive?
>
> Or are there examples of $k$-distance-transitive graphs of arbitrary large diameter, that are not distance-transitive even if $k=\mathrm{diam}(G)-1$?

Comment: It seems you're considering connected graphs. You're also assuming graphs are finite, right?

Comment: @YCor Yes, I will edit this in. What has this question to do with (metric) geometry?

Comment: Metric geometry is, to a large extent, the study of metric spaces, including their isometry groups. Connected graphs provide a very nice and important supply of metric spaces. The notion of distance transitivity (isometry group is transitive on pairs at given distance) is a purely metric notion.

Comment: Just a small comment: if we have a $k$-distance-transitive graph, and the girth is also large (I think at least $2k$), then it must also be $k$-arc-transitive. It is known that there are no finite $8$-arc-transitive graphs except cycles. So, if you want examples with large $k$, then you need small(ish) girth.

Comment: Actually, here's an improvement on this argument: it is known that there is an absolute constant $c$ such that, in a finite $2$-arc-transitive graph, fixing (pointwise) a ball of radius $c$ around a vertex fixes everything. (This is due to Trofimov and Weiss. I think you can take $c$ to be $5$ or $6$.) Now, if your family is going to be $k$-distance-transitive for large $k$ smaller than the diameter, with $k$ growing, then I think it cannot have the property above. In particular, the large $k$ examples cannot be $2$-arc-transitive. In particular, they must have girth $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a related result that I wanted to share.
Note that $k$-distance-transitivity is generalized by $k$-walk-regularity. In

- Camara, van Dam, Koolen, Park: ["Geometric aspects of 2-walk-regular graphs"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.2905.pdf)

the authors prove the following (see Corollary 6.4):

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a $k$-walk-regular graph of degree $d$ with an eigenvalue $\theta\not\in\{-d,d\}$ of multiplicity at most $k$. If $k\ge 2$, then $G$ is distance-regular.

So $k$-walk-regular graphs that are not distance-regular must have only eigenvalues of large multiplicity (excluding $\theta=\pm d$).
Maybe something similar is true in the case of distance-transitivity.